# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore().......set is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firebase to develop a web app.
I got this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore(...).collection(...).orderBy(...).limit(...).set is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:152)
```

because of this code.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('script').orderBy('timestamp','desc').limit(1).set({
    finaltext: resultText.value,
    name: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  },{merge: true}).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Error writing new message to Firestore', error);
  });
```

I searched the Internet, but couldn't find why this error message occurred.
Could you give me any advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first fetch the desired document, with [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get), before writing the new field(s) with [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) (with merge option) or [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update).

```
firebase.firestore().collection('script').orderBy('timestamp','desc').limit(1).get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        //We are sure the document exists, we can then use update()
        return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
          finaltext: resultText.value,
          name: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
          uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        });
    } else {
       throw new Error("No document");
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Note that the `get()` method returns a `QuerySnapshot`, so you need to do `querySnapshot.docs[0]` to get the `DocumentSnapshot` corresponding to the unique doc returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

The method `limit` returns a value of type `Query`:

> limit
>
> `limit ( limit :  number ) : Query < T >`
>
> Creates and returns a new Query that only returns the first matching documents.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#limit

Therefore both `orderBy` and `limit` are used when you want to retrieve data. If you want to add data to the database then just do the following:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('script').set({
    finaltext: resultText.value,
    name: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  },{merge: true}).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Error writing new message to Firestore', error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to update the document which was made latest. So, collection from 'script', order by timestamp and limit one document. I would like to update, not add. I hope my words convey what I want to do.

Comment: You need to use `get()` then instead of set https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: Thank you for reply. If I use ```get()```, I only get the document. The document already has field and data, so I want to add new field and data.

Comment: I chose another person for best answer, but I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you.